# Outlook 2010 to 2011 sync removes contact picture

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I start with a perfect contact in Outlook 2010 on my work PC. At home, I open the contact in Office 2011 on my MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion. All is well. But when I open the contact again in Outlook 2010, the picture is no longer displayed, but the image is in the notes field as ContactPicture.jpg. The same contact on my Mac still looks ok, though.

This is an Exchange 2010 e-mail account.

How can I stop this from happening, aside from never opening Outlook 2011?

Is there a way to put the contact picture back where it goes, other than one-by-one saving the image to my desktop and importing it back into the contact?

Almost forgot – I also sync this account with my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the same problem using Outlook 2010 on Exchange (PC), Outlook for Mac on MacBook Air and both iPhone 5 and iPad.  I have learned that by adding the picture on Outlook 2010 when sync completes the ContactPicture.jpg is added to the Notes field.  The ContactPicture.jpg shows only in Outlook 2010 on Exchange and is NOT shown in Notes on the Mac, iPhone or iPad.  If you delete the ContactPicture.jpg in Notes, the pic will be removed from the iPhone and iPad but remain in Outlook for Mac.
Conclusions:
 1. There is a sync issue.
 2. Add the pic on Outlook 2010, leave the ContactPicture.jpg alone in the Notes field.